# Optional route parameters not working in Lumen 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing, lumen, laravel-route

I had defined my route and controller as following

```
$router->group(['prefix' => 'api/v1'], function ($router) {
    $router->group(
     ['middleware' => 'auth'], function() use ($router) {
     $router->get('/order/get-order-status/{order_id}[/{account_id}]'
                , [
                'uses' => 'Api\V1\OrderController@getOrderStatus'
                , 'as' => 'getOrderStatus'
                ]
     );
  });
});
```

following is the function defination

```
public function getOrderStatus($orderId, $accountId = false)
{
   // my code goes here
}
```

Here the problem is whenever, I skip the optional `account_id` from the route, then passed `order_id` is assigned to the 2nd parameter of the function i,e. `accountId`. If I pass both params then everything is working as expected. I'm just confused whether something is wrong in my configuration or `Lumen` itself have some issue with optional route params?

Consider I had triggered `http://localhost/lumen/api/v1/order/get-order-status/ORD1234` then `ORD1234` is assigned to `accountId` and '0' is assigned to `orderId`

Comment: Your url and your route are different. On your route you say it has to be like this: http://localhost/lumen/api/v1/order/get-order-status/ORD1234[/1]. however the route your are triggering is http://localhost/lumen/api/v1/order/get-order-status/ORD1234

Answer (score 1):

optional route parameters are given like below,

```
$router->get('/order/get-order-status/{order_id}/{account_id?}' // see the ? mark
```

though I am not sure why 0 is assigned to the orderId,

and usually, the first parameter to the controller method is a request object, so you can easily identify what are the things that the request contains.

```
public function getOrderStatus(Request $reqeust, $orderId, $accountId = false)
```

Comment: I had tried your approach too, whenever I'm using '?', I'm getting 404 error.

Comment: sorry, there is no need of square brackets, Even I haven't noticed, check the edited answer

Answer (score 0):

move out your optional parameter route outside the group

```
$router->group(['prefix' => 'api/v1'], function ($router) {
 $router->get('/order/get-order-status/{order_id}[/{account_id}]'
            , [
            ,'middleware' => 'auth',
            'uses' => 'Api\V1\OrderController@getOrderStatus'
            , 'as' => 'getOrderStatus'
            ]
 );
```

or like this following code

```
$router->get('api/v1/order/get-order-status/{order_id}[/{account_id}]', 
                    ['uses' => 'Api\V1\OrderController@getOrderStatus',
                    'middleware' => 'auth',
                    'as' => 'getOrderStatus'
                    ]
         );
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use optional parameter like

> `{account_id?}` rather then `[/{account_id}]`